My implementation for reproducing a paper
I'm trying to reproduce this paper. I've basically done everything and I've obtained the final expression of page 3. My only problem is that my implementation gets slow for larger numbers really fast.
from sympy import IndexedBase, expand, Indexed, Mul
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

x = IndexedBase('x')

def high_degree_f(N, l1 = 2, l2 = 3):
    # p and q are binary numbers of length l1 and l2
    p = 1
    q = 1

    for i in range(1, l1):
        p += x[i] * 2**i

    for idx, l in enumerate(range(l1, l1+l2 - 1)):
        q += x[l] * 2**(idx+1)

    f = (N - p * q ) **2
    f = expand(f)
    r = len(f.free_symbols) + 1

    # replace x[i]**k by x[i] as x[i] is binary
    for i in range(1, r):
        for k in range(2, 4):
            f = f.subs(x[i]**k, x[i])
    return (f, p, q)

def out_degrees_more_than_2(f):
    # Iterate over the terms in the expanded polynomial
    for term in f.as_ordered_terms():
        # Check if the term is a product
        if isinstance(term, Mul):
            # Count the number of Indexed instances in the term
            variable_count = sum(isinstance(factor, Indexed) for factor in term.args)
            # Check if there are more than two variables in the product
            if variable_count > 2:
                # Print the term
                yield (variable_count, term)

def max_degree(f):
    max_degree = 0
    for (variable_count, term) in out_degrees_more_than_2(f):
        max_degree = max(max_degree, variable_count)
    return max_degree

def reduced_f(N, l1 = 2, l2 = 3):

    (f, p, q) = high_degree_f(N, l1 = l1, l2 = l2)
    number_of_variables = len(f.free_symbols) - 1

    while max_degree(f) > 2:
        for (variable_count, term) in tqdm(out_degrees_more_than_2(f)):
            if variable_count == 3:

                # extract the numerical coefficient of the term:
                coefficient, v = term.as_coeff_Mul()
                variables = v.args

                new_term = coefficient* (variables[2] * x[number_of_variables+1] + 2 * ( variables[0] * variables[1] - 2 * variables[0] * x[number_of_variables+1] - 2 * variables[1] * x[number_of_variables+1] + 3 * x[number_of_variables+1]))
                number_of_variables += 1
                
                # substitute the term with the new term
                f = f.subs(term, new_term)
            elif variable_count == 4:
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unexpected number of variables in term")
        f = expand(f)

    return (f, p, q)

N = 15
l1 = 2
l2 = 3

(f, p, q) = reduced_f(N, l1 = l1, l2 = l2)

print("N:\t\t", N)
print("p:\t\t", p)
print("q:\t\t", q)
print("Reduced f:\t", f)

N:               15
p:               2*x[1] + 1
q:               2*x[2] + 4*x[3] + 1
Reduced f:       200*x[1]*x[2] - 48*x[1]*x[3] - 512*x[1]*x[4] - 52*x[1] + 16*x[2]*x[3] - 512*x[2]*x[4] - 52*x[2] + 128*x[3]*x[4] - 96*x[3] + 768*x[4] + 196  

expression from paper:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}f^{\prime} (x) & = & 200{x}{1}{x}{2}-48{x}{1}{x}{3}-512{x}{1}{x}{4}+16{x}{2}{x}{3}-512{x}{2}{x}{4}+128{x}{3}{x}{4}\  &  & -52{x}{1}-52{x}{2}-96{x}{3}+768{x}{4}+\mathrm{196,}\end{array}$$
But for N = 10403, l1 = 7, l2 = 7, it takes minutes to get the final expression. Can anyone suggest any improvement to my implementation?

This seems more suitable for [codereview.se].

Here are all the changes that I made to routines to avoid rebuilding Mul and Add objects:
from sympy import IndexedBase, expand, Indexed, Mul
from sympy.core.function import _mexpand
import numpy as np
#from tqdm import tqdm
#tqdm=lambda x:x
x = IndexedBase('x')

def high_degree_f(N, l1 = 2, l2 = 3):
    # p and q are binary numbers of length l1 and l2
    p = [1]
    q = [1]

    for i in range(1, l1):
        p.append(x[i] * 2**i)

    for idx, l in enumerate(range(l1, l1+l2 - 1)):
        q.append(x[l] * 2**(idx+1))

    p,q = [Add(*i) for i in (p,q)]
    f = (N - p * q ) **2
    f = _mexpand(f)
    r = len(f.free_symbols) + 1

    # replace x[i]**k by x[i] as x[i] is binary
    for i in range(1, r):
        for k in range(2, 4):
            f = f.subs(x[i]**k, x[i])
    return (f, p, q)

def out_degrees_more_than_2(f):
    # Iterate over the terms in the expanded polynomial
    for term in f.as_ordered_terms():
        # Check if the term is a product
        if len(v:=term.as_coeff_mul()[1])>2:
            yield (len(v), term)

def max_degree(f):
    max_degree = 0
    for (variable_count, term) in out_degrees_more_than_2(f):
        max_degree = max(max_degree, variable_count)
    return max_degree

def reduced_f(N, l1 = 2, l2 = 3):

    (f, p, q) = high_degree_f(N, l1 = l1, l2 = l2)
    number_of_variables = len(f.free_symbols) - 1

    while max_degree(f) > 2:
        for (variable_count, term) in (out_degrees_more_than_2(f)):
            if variable_count == 3:
                coefficient, variables = term.as_coeff_mul()
                new_term = coefficient* (variables[2] * x[number_of_variables+1] + 2 * ( variables[0] * variables[1] - 2 * variables[0] * x[number_of_variables+1] - 2 * variables[1] * x[number_of_variables+1] + 3 * x[number_of_variables+1]))
                number_of_variables += 1
                
                # substitute the term with the new term
                f = f.xreplace({term: new_term})
            elif variable_count == 4:
                pass
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unexpected number of variables in term")
        f = _mexpand(f)

    return (f, p, q)

from time import time
N = 15; l1 = 2; l2 = 3
T=time()
(f, p, q) = reduced_f(N, l1 = l1, l2 = l2)
print(N,time()-T,f)
N = 10403; l1 = 7; l2 = 7
T=time()
(f, p, q) = reduced_f(N, l1 = l1, l2 = l2)
print(N,time()-T,f)


While very fast, this does not answer my question. The heavy-lifting part of the code happens in reduced_f routine where the f is actually reduced. You're code skips that part completely and outputs a high degree polynomial. @smichr

I posted the routine I modified. I ran your code (with that routine) with the numbers you gave: it took less than a second to run. What did you obtain for a new time with the new routine? A further (premature?) optimization is to replace coefficient, v = term.as_coeff_Mul(); variables = v.args with coefficient, variables = term.as_coeff_mul().

if you print(f), your answer outputs 128*x[1]*x[2]*x[3] - 56*x[1]*x[2] - 48*x[1]*x[3] - 52*x[1] + 16*x[2]*x[3] - 52*x[2] - 96*x[3] + 196 . Note that it is different from the output I gave in the body of my question! The reason is that the your code skips the reduced_f part, which is already where the slow operations happen.

When I make modifications, verify the same output for your small N case, and test for the large N case, it takes a long time so the changes are not useful.
